# How can I add scopes to `security.HTTPBearer[]` for a route using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

How can I add scopes to `security.HTTPBearer[]` for the `GET /v1/health` route using FastAPI?

I have checked the docs for `HTTPBearer`, but it doesn't seem to support any way of adding scopes.

I would like `security.HTTPBearer[]` to be equal to e.g. `["read", "me"]`.

Thank you!

**Code**:

```
security = HTTPBearer()

@v1_router.get(
    "/health",
    tags=["healthcheck"],
    summary="Perform a Health Check",
    response_description="Return HTTP Status Code 200 (OK)",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=HealthCheck,
)
def get_health(credentials: Annotated[HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, Depends(security)]) -> HealthCheck:
    return HealthCheck()
```

**JSON**:

```
"/v1/health": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "healthcheck"
    ],
    "summary": "Perform a Health Check",
    "operationId": "get_health_v1_health_get",
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Return HTTP Status Code 200 (OK)",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HealthCheck"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "security": [
      {
        "HTTPBearer": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `OAuth2PasswordBearer`  or `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` instead of `HTTPBearer`? as HTTPBearer itself does not directly support scopes. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/

Comment: Thank you, but isn't `OAuth2PasswordBearer` only for OAuth2` using a password like resource-owner password credentials grant?